# Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path' in my maze path finding program?

Tags: python, path-finding, nonetype

I am trying to create a Python program using Jupiter Notebook and the A* algorithm, which finds the shortest path out of a hashtag maze. I keep getting the error that the 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be occurring? I did override the result method, so I am not sure whether that may be causing the issue, but I am uncertain how I could fix this.

The error is-

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 57>()
     88 problem = MazeSolver(MAP)
     90 result = astar(problem, graph_search=True)
---> 92 path = [x[1] for x in result.path()]
     94 print()
     95 for y in range(len(MAP)):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'
```

---

```
import math
from simpleai.search import SearchProblem, astar

class MazeSolver(SearchProblem):
    
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.goal = (0,0)
        
        for y in range(len(self.board)):
            for x in range(len(self.board[y])):
                if self.board[y][x].lower() == "o":
                    self.initial = (x, y)
                elif self.board[y][x].lower() == "x":
                    self.goal = (x, y)
        super(MazeSolver, self).__init__(initial_state = self.initial)
                
    
    def actions(self, state):
        actions = []
        for action in COSTS.keys():
            newx, newy = self.result(state, actions)
            if self.board[newy][newx] != "#":
                actions.append(action)
        return actions
    
    

    def result(self, state, action):
        x, y = state
        
        if action.count("up"):
            y -= 1
        if action.count("down"):
            y += 1
        if action.count("left"):
            x -= 1
        if action.count("right"):
            x += 1
            
        new_state = (x, y)
        
        return new_state
    
    def is_goal(self, state):
        return state == self.goal
        
    def cost(self, state, action, state2):
        return COSTS[action]
    
    def heuristic(self, state):
        x, y = state
        gx, gy = self.goal
        
        return math.sqrt((x - gx) ** 2 + (y - gy) ** 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MAP = """
    #############################
    #        #              #   #
    # ####   ########       #   #
    #  o #   #              #   #
    #    ###    #####  ######   #
    #      #   ###  #           #
    #      #     #  #  #  #   ###
    #     #####    #   #  # x   #
    #              #      #     #
    #############################
    """
    
    print(MAP)
    MAP = [list(x) for x in MAP.split("\n") if x]
    
    cost_regular = 1.0
    cost_diagonal = 1.7
    
    COSTS = {
        "up": cost_regular,
        "down": cost_regular,
        "left": cost_regular,
        "right": cost_regular,
        "up left": cost_diagonal,
        "up right": cost_diagonal,
        "down left": cost_diagonal,
        "down right": cost_diagonal
    }

    problem = MazeSolver(MAP)
    
    result = astar(problem, graph_search=True)
    
    path = [x[1] for x in result.path()]
    
    print()
    for y in range(len(MAP)):
        for x in range(len(MAP[y])):
            if (x, y) == problem.initial:
                print('o', end='')
            elif(x, y) == problem.goal:
                print('x', end='')
            elif (x, y) in path:
                print('.', end='')
            else:
                print(MAP[y][x], end='')
        print()
```

Comment: We cannot possibly know because you don't tell us what `astar` (`result = astar(problem, graph_search=True)`) is.

Comment: Missed this out in the code-

import math
from simpleai.search import SearchProblem, astar

Comment: Where does it say that `astar` returns something other than `None`?

Comment: Looks like [astar](https://github.com/simpleai-team/simpleai/blob/cf59ead2b8733e680178614384b3cc6d458ad143/simpleai/search/traditional.py#L108) only returns something if the goal is found.  You need to check for `None` before using `result`.

Comment: astar was returning None because in line newx, newy = self.result(state, actions) within the actions function it's meant to be action not actions- all is working now, thank you!!